# How to do a binary search for a range of the same value?

Tags: python, binary-search

I have a sorted list of numbers and I need to get it return the range of index that the number appears. My list is:

```
daysSick = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 11, 15, 24]
```

If I searched 0, I need to return (0, 3). Right now I can only get it to find the spot of one number! I know how to do the binary search, but I am stuck how to make it move up and down from the position to find the other same values!

```
low = 0
high = len(daysSick) - 1
while low <= high :
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    if value < daysSick[mid]:
        high = mid - 1
    elif value > list[mid]:
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        return mid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I present a solution faster than the [raw functions taken](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py) from the `bisect` library

#### Solution

With *Optimised* Binary Search

```
def search(a, x):
    right = 0
    h = len(a)
    while right < h:
        m = (right+h)//2
        if x < a[m]: h = m
        else: 
            right = m+1
    # start binary search for left element only 
    # including elements from 0 to right-1 - much faster!
    left = 0
    h = right - 1
    while left < h:
        m = (left+h)//2
        if x > a[m]: left = m+1
        else: 
            h = m
    return left, right-1

search(daysSick, 5)
(10, 12)

search(daysSick, 2)
(5, 5)
```

#### Comparision vs. `Bisect`

- Using customised binary search...

  ```
  %timeit search(daysSick, 3)
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 µs per loop
  ```
- Copying the raw code from the source from `bisect` into python...

  ```
  %timeit bisect_left(daysSick, 1), bisect_right(daysSick, 1)
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 µs per loop
  ```
- Using default import is by far the fastest as I think it might be optimised behind the scenes ...

  ```
  from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
  %timeit bisect_left(daysSick, 1), bisect_right(daysSick, 1)
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 504 ns per loop
  ```

#### Extra

Without ext. libraries but not binary search

```
daysSick = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 11, 15, 24]

# using a function
idxL = lambda val, lst:  [i for i,d in enumerate(lst) if d==val]

allVals = idxL(0,daysSick)
(0, 3)
```

Comment: Well, then OP's binary search is not needed at all since you scan entire list here.

Comment: @Alik I posted before he stated that the answer had to include a binary search in part of it. My solution was just to answer the Q without importing libraries

Comment: @Terrance Seo - I edited to include an optimised binary search for your problem

Comment: It looks like the bisect module is more than twice as fast.  Am I reading your results wrong?!

Comment: @wim it's because the built in module is raw C code. That's why I copied the bisect python source code to made it a fair comparison. If you took my optimised code and translated it into C / Fortran it would beat the built in module as shown in the python vs. python comparison.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [Python's bisection routines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) from the stdlib:

```
>>> daysSick = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 11, 15, 24]
>>> from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
>>> bisect_left(daysSick, 3)
6
>>> bisect_right(daysSick, 3)
9
>>> daysSick[6:9]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: @TerranceSeo, see the link in the comments, there is nothing special about the bisect methods, they are implemented in pure python.

Comment: @wim OP wants the actual indices, i.e. `6, 8` - you would need to subtract `1` from `bisect_right()`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's not correct, they are implemented in C.  there is a reference python implementation for fallback, but it is not used normally.

Comment: The c implementation if used if available.  The op is looking for the algorithms which are in the link i posted.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's another way that works by attempting to reduce the range first before doing `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` on half of the already-reduced range. I wrote this code because I think it is *slightly* more efficient than just calling `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` even though it has the same time complexity.

```
def binary_range_search(s, x):
    # First we will reduce the low..high range if possible
    # by using symmetric binary search to find an index pointing to x
    low, high = 0, len(s)
    while True:
        if low >= high:
            return None
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        mid_element = s[mid]
        if x == mid_element:
            break
        elif x < mid_element:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    xindex = mid

    # Now we have found an index pointing to x called xindex
    # and potentially reduced the low..high range
    # now we can run bisect_left on low..xindex + 1

    lo, hi = low, xindex + 1
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x > s[mid]: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    first = lo

    # and also bisect_right on xindex..high

    lo, hi = xindex, high
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < s[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    last = lo - 1

    return first, last
```

I think the time complexity is O(log n) just like the trivial solution, but I believe this is a bit more efficient regardless. I think it's worth noting that the second part where you do `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` can be parallelized for large data sets since they are independent operations that do not interact.

Answer (score 0):

- Find floor : index of number  < key
- Find ceiling : index of number > key
- [floor + 1 , ceiling - 1] gives you the range.

```
# yields next highest or lowest number to the key
# isLessThan determines which way the pointer moves

def nextNumber(arr, key, isLessThan):
  lo, hi = 0, len(arr)-1
  
  while lo <= hi:
    mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2

    if isLessThan(key, arr[mid]):
      hi = mid - 1
    else:
      lo = mid + 1
  
  return (lo, hi)

def ceiling(arr, key):
  lo,_ = nextNumber(arr, key, lambda x,y : x < y)
  return lo

def floor(arr, key):
  _,hi = nextNumber(arr, key, lambda x,y : x <= y)
  return hi


def find_range(arr, key):
  fl = floor(arr,key)

  # key not in array
  if fl+1 >= len(arr) or arr[fl+1] != key:
    return [-1,-1]
  
  cl = ceiling(arr,key)
  return [fl+1 , cl-1]
```