# Why is this imported default module far faster than its raw source

Tags: python, performance, optimization, python-import

This question arises from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794570/4013571) I provided to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794533/how-to-do-a-binary-search-for-a-range-of-the-same-value) *(optimising a binary search for a specific purpose)*

The example is the `bisect` library.

When I run the `bisect` library using the default `from bisect import *`, it's `>3.5` times faster than its own [raw source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py) pasted into `ipython`...

```
# define array
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 11, 15, 24]

# Copying the raw code from the source from bisect into ipython
# using ipython's magic %paste command
%paste
...
%timeit bisect_left(a, 1), bisect_right(a, 1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 µs per loop

# now importing and using the python default functions...
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
%timeit bisect_left(a, 1), bisect_right(a, 1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 504 ns per loop
```

**Question**

1. What causes this speed-up.
2. How can I gain this speed-up with my own code?

Comment: Did you copy the `from _bisect import *` part? `bisect` doesn't actually use any of the functions it defines, since they're all replaced by the C versions from `_bisect`.

Comment: That is the answer.  The python reference implementations are only there incase the imports from C extensions fail for some reason

Comment: @user2357112 / @wim - do you know where I can find the `cython` code for `_bisect`?

Comment: @alexmcf: [`Modules/_bisectmodule.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3156dd82df2d/Modules/_bisectmodule.c). It's not Cython; it's written directly in C.

Comment: ha no wonder my python code was 3 times slower despite having optimisations ! I should have written my solution in `Fortran` >_>